# Moving my drawing tablet from one computer to another

Tags: drivers, tablet, chromebook

I'm not really a "computer person", so I thought I'd come to the experts with this question ;)

I have a drawing tablet (Monoprice brand) that I use for animation and digital art. To use it, I had to install drivers using a CD-ROM that came with the tablet. I could only install the drivers onto one computer, though, so I chose my desktop.

I have a new laptop now, and I want to use my tablet with it. So pretty much I have two questions:

1) Will a Chromebook (my new laptop) run tablet drivers? It has a USB port but I'm not sure if it will run the drivers or recognize it as a mouse (like my other computer does.)

2) If it will, is there a way to move the drivers from my desktop to my laptop?

Thanks :)
Tess

Comment: _"I could only install the drivers onto one computer"_ - why?

Comment: @gronostaj The CD-rom wouldn't let me install on more than one computer. It said I had already installed it :\